# How to search text based on line number in string

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have a function which searching a text in a string and returning me the line which contains the specific substring.Here is the function..

```
private static string getLine(string text,string text2Search)
{
    string currentLine;
    using (var reader = new StringReader(text)) 
    {
        while ((currentLine= reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
        {
            if (currentLine.Contains(text2Search,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return currentLine;
}
```

Now in my condition i have to start searching the lines after a particular line suppose here its 10.Means  have to start searching the string for specific text after 10 line.So my query is how can i add this into my current function..
Please help me.

Comment: Are you trying to return all lines after you've found this line or just search them for other text?

Comment: I want to return only one line say after 10th line which contains the `texttosearch`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a counter into your current code as so:

```
private static string getLine(string text,string text2Search)
{
    string currentLine;
    int endPoint = 10;
    using (var reader = new StringReader(text)) 
    {
        int lineCount = 0;
        while ((currentLine= reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
        {
            if (lineCount++ >= endPoint && 
                currentLine.Contains(text2Search,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return currentLine;
            }
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Alternatively, use your current code to add all lines to a list in which you will then be able to use Selmans answer.

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile. What if there is no match?

Comment: @EZI - Good point, I changed the code back to what it was originally. **Edit**: Actually, I've changed it again to return an empty string if none found since I don't like the idea of the last line being returned

Answer (score 4):

You can use `File.ReadLines` method with `Skip`:

```
var line = File.ReadLines("path").Skip(10)
.SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains(text2Search,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
.First();
```

Comment: +1 my thoughts exactly (I would've used `FirstOfDefault` though, not sure if there is always a match).

Comment: I have string with me and no Files So i cant use  `File.ReadLines`

Comment: @user3924730 no, you can absolutely use File.ReadLines.

Answer (score 0):

String.Contains doesn't have an overload taking `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`

```
var match = text.Split(new char[]{'\n','\r'})
            .Skip(10)
            .FirstOrDefault(line=>line.IndexOf("", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)>=0);
```